# How to make a custom http client in Go?

Tags: go, request, client

I want to create a custom http Client so I can reuse it as many times as possible.
However, I think Go has abstracted some of the processes that happen behind the code.
I understand that to have a get request a client must have been created.

Where is the client created and how can I customize it or replace it with my own?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/njasm/gosoundcloud"
)

 s, err = gosoundcloud.NewSoundcloudApi("Client_Id", "Client_Secret", nil)


func main() {
    if err = s.PasswordCredentialsToken("email@example.com", "password"); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
    member, err := s.GetUser(uint64(1))
    if err != nil {
               panic(err)
     }
    fmt.Println(member.Followers)
}
```

Here are the references of the soundcloud wrapper:

```
func NewSoundcloudApi(c string, cs string, callback *string) (*SoundcloudApi, error)

func (s *SoundcloudApi) PasswordCredentialsToken(u string, p string) error

func (s *SoundcloudApi) GetUser(id uint64) (*User, error)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Golang, you can easily create a client and use it for a request:

```
client := &http.Client{
    CheckRedirect: redirectPolicyFunc,
}

resp, err := client.Get("http://example.com")
```

[See the http documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/)

But in your case, according to the gosoundcloud package you are using, the http.Client is created when calling:

```
s.PasswordCredentialsToken("email@example.com", "password");
```

The created client is embedded into the "SoundcloudApi" struct (the "s" in your code), and is a private field. Thus, you can't access it.

Anyway it seems to be used anytime you ask "s" to do something (when calling s.User for example), so it seems to do what you are asking for.

Comment: Why do you say it is a private field?

Comment: Because it is part of the language: [https://tour.golang.org/basics/3]. A name starting with a capital letter is exported (public), if it doesn't it is not exported (private).